# Drupal - Theme a node type using CSS

Tags: html, css, drupal

Hey, I have some content I am trying to save as a node. The problem is the content i am trying to save is html and even with drupal set to "Full HTML" input format it's still not displaying correctly.

Here is what I am trying to post, personal info removed.

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<DIV style="position:relative;width:612;height:792;">
<STYLE type="text/css">
<!--
 .ft0{font-size:8px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#000000;}
 .ft1{font-size:4px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#000000;}
 .ft2{font-size:5px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#000000;}
 .ft3{font-size:10px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#000000;}
 .ft4{font-size:8px;line-height:12px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#000000;}
 .ft5{font-size:4px;line-height:7px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#000000;}
 .ft6{font-size:8px;line-height:2px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#000000;}
 .ft7{font-size:8px;line-height:3px;font-family:Helvetica;color:#000000;}
-->
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#A0A0A0" vlink="blue" link="blue">
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:284;left:34"><nobr><span class="ft0">****</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:284;left:160"><nobr><span class="ft0">MIC</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:284;left:232"><nobr><span class="ft0">*********</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:168;left:48"><nobr><span class="ft0">************</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:284;left:437"><nobr><span class="ft0">**/**/2010</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:181;left:48"><nobr><span class="ft4">****** St<br>******* 48602</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:125;left:40"><nobr><span class="ft0">**********************</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:54;left:60"><nobr><span class="ft0">*********</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:54;left:317"><nobr><span class="ft0">1st*****</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:84;left:431"><nobr><span class="ft0">**/**/2010</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:84;left:520"><nobr><span class="ft0">      $00000</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:298;left:30"><nobr><span class="ft1">EMPLOYEE NO.</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:298;left:154"><nobr><span class="ft1">LOCATION</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:298;left:233"><nobr><span class="ft1">EMPLOYEE  NAME</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:298;left:445"><nobr><span class="ft1">PERIOD END</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:311;left:151"><nobr><span class="ft1">HRS/UNITS</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:311;left:199"><nobr><span class="ft1">CURRENT AMOUNT</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:311;left:279"><nobr><span class="ft1">YEAR TO DATE</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:310;left:372"><nobr><span class="ft2">DEDUCTIONS</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:310;left:60"><nobr><span class="ft2">EARNINGS</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:311;left:534"><nobr><span class="ft1">YEAR TO DATE</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:311;left:459"><nobr><span class="ft1">CURRENT AMOUNT</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:73;left:447"><nobr><span class="ft1">DATE</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:73;left:521"><nobr><span class="ft1">AMOUNT</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:169;left:19"><nobr><span class="ft5">TO THE<br>ORDER<br>OF</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:125;left:19"><nobr><span class="ft2">PAY</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:182;left:343"><nobr><span class="ft2">Bank Routing No.</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:182;left:417"><nobr><span class="ft2">Bank Account Number</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:181;left:515"><nobr><span class="ft2">Deposit Amount</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:195;left:528"><nobr><span class="ft0">    99999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:195;left:418"><nobr><span class="ft0">9999-000</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:195;left:336"><nobr><span class="ft0">9999999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:258;left:253"><nobr><span class="ft3"><b>NON NEGOTIABLE</b></span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:67;left:60"><nobr><span class="ft4">1212 N. *****<br>*****, MI 99999-</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:9;left:4"><nobr><span class="ft6">.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:5;left:4"><nobr><span class="ft0">.</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:27;left:4"><nobr><span class="ft0">.</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:3;left:4"><nobr><span class="ft0">.</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:29;left:4"><nobr><span class="ft0">.</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:284;left:103"><nobr><span class="ft0">01</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:298;left:102"><nobr><span class="ft1">SHIFT</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:324;left:25"><nobr><span class="ft0">Regular Pay</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:324;left:348"><nobr><span class="ft0">Federal Income</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:324;left:153"><nobr><span class="ft0">  7999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:324;left:210"><nobr><span class="ft0">     9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:324;left:281"><nobr><span class="ft0">     9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:324;left:471"><nobr><span class="ft0">      9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:324;left:540"><nobr><span class="ft0">     9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:338;left:25"><nobr><span class="ft0">Overtime Pay</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:338;left:348"><nobr><span class="ft0">Medicare Tax</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:338;left:156"><nobr><span class="ft0">   0.000</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:338;left:217"><nobr><span class="ft0">        0.00</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:338;left:283"><nobr><span class="ft0">      9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:338;left:474"><nobr><span class="ft0">       9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:338;left:543"><nobr><span class="ft0">      9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:353;left:25"><nobr><span class="ft0">Vacation Pay</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:353;left:348"><nobr><span class="ft0">FICA Tax</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:353;left:156"><nobr><span class="ft0">   9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:353;left:212"><nobr><span class="ft0">      9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:353;left:283"><nobr><span class="ft0">      9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:353;left:474"><nobr><span class="ft0">       9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:353;left:540"><nobr><span class="ft0">     9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:367;left:348"><nobr><span class="ft0">Michigan Income</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:367;left:474"><nobr><span class="ft0">       9999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:367;left:540"><nobr><span class="ft0">     99999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:381;left:348"><nobr><span class="ft0">Saginaw Residen</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:381;left:474"><nobr><span class="ft0">       999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:381;left:543"><nobr><span class="ft0">      57999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:395;left:348"><nobr><span class="ft0">Hth Ins. Co-Pay</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:395;left:471"><nobr><span class="ft0">      11999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:395;left:540"><nobr><span class="ft0">     29999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:409;left:348"><nobr><span class="ft0">Dental Co-Pay</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:409;left:474"><nobr><span class="ft0">       19999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:409;left:543"><nobr><span class="ft0">     999999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:423;left:348"><nobr><span class="ft0">Vision Co-Pay</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:423;left:476"><nobr><span class="ft0">       999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:423;left:543"><nobr><span class="ft0">      19999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:668;left:116"><nobr><span class="ft0">      169999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:668;left:287"><nobr><span class="ft0">      19999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:668;left:202"><nobr><span class="ft0">       999999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:668;left:370"><nobr><span class="ft0">     999999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:668;left:456"><nobr><span class="ft0">     999999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:668;left:534"><nobr><span class="ft0">     999999</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:681;left:102"><nobr><span class="ft1">CURRENT EARNINGS</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:681;left:184"><nobr><span class="ft1">CURRENT DEDUCTIONS</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:679;left:288"><nobr><span class="ft2">NET PAY</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:681;left:365"><nobr><span class="ft1">Y.T.D. EARNINGS</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:681;left:446"><nobr><span class="ft1">Y.T.D. DEDUCTIONS</span></nobr></DIV>
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:681;left:532"><nobr><span class="ft1">Y.T.D. NET PAY</span></nobr></DIV>
</DIV>
```

It should look like a paystub, with everything aligned properly, the text is a little small but that is easily fixed but I cannot figure out why everything is just left aligned after i save the node. I have tried all three input formats all not giving me what I want. Any ideas? I am fairly new to

this installation of Drupal is only on our intranet and pertains to pay-stubs and all that good personal info that I'm sure someone would love to get there hands on. So I'm unable to give you a live link of anything.

I can tell you that its just a default installation of Drupal so I can be fairly sure nothing wonky is going on under the hood. I tried removing the head and body tags from the HTML to no avail.

When "Full HTML" input mode is enabled after the save, the font sizing works correctly, and the background color is changed to grey which is in the HTML code I posted so those parts are working. What seems to be missing is the positioning of the text.

Here is a screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gsuW.png

Comment: Have a look at the HTML that Drupal generates when displaying the node. Are there any HTML elements missing compared to your original HTML? Are there any HTML attributes missing? Please tell us.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems. It's hard to say which might be causing the absolution positioning to fail, but here are some things to fix regardless:

1. You don't need a meta tag. Drupal
   already does that (2, actually).
2. You shouldn't put a `<style>` tag in
   your markup. Use the [CSS module](http://drupal.org/project/css) for node-specific CSS.
3. You can't have a `<body>` tag in
   your node. The node exists within
   the `<body>`, so this gives you a
   structure of body > div > body >
   div. I suspect this is the root of
   your problem.
4. You should be using
   [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_white-space.asp)
   in CSS rather than `<nobr>`.
5. Stop capitalizing your tags. It doesn't
   break anything, but makes you look
   like a crazy person who screams all
   the time.

If all of that doesn't solve your problem, install Firebug to see whether your style attribute is being applied and/or whether something else is overriding it.

Comment: Haha, thanks. I did already try removing the <body> tags with no success. All of the html is generated by a program called pdftohtml before its imported programmatically into Drupal. Obviously thats what im trying to figure out right now is the drupal part.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why it works outside of drupal but not inside. If I save the file as an .html file and open it in a browser or inside Dreamweaver it is formatted correctly.